# JSF selectManyCheckbox converter to String

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to write converter which can convert `String[]` to String?

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.numbers}" > 
  <f:selectItem itemValue="Number10" itemLabel="Number 10" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="Number20" itemLabel="Number 20" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="Number30" itemLabel="Number 30" />
  <f:converter converterId="arrayStringConverter"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I need to declare `#{bean.numbers}` as String. I know that `selectManyCheckbox` requires Array or Collection.

How can I write converter that can convert array to separated string? I've tried using f:converter but it's called for every `f:selectItem`, but not for the whole component value.

Comment: Where do you need that value later? Just save it as a collection and convert to String when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

The JSF converter is applied repeatedly on every individual item, not once on the whole collection/array as you seemd to expect. So, no, that's not possible. If you absolutely need to malform the model like this, just perform the conversion job afterwards in the business layer.

*(if I guess right what you're actually trying to do, storing multiple values commaseparated in a single DB column; start reading about DB normalization, foreign key relationships and JOINs)*